# Custom Keyboard app with custom emojis

Tags: image, keyboard, emoji, custom-keyboard, custom-application

I would like create a custom emoji keyboard app that allows me to add an emoji(.png) right next to the text. Like the normal keyboarbs emojis in IOS and Andriod. Is it possible?

Instead of these [emojis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIv4t.png) , i want to create custom made .png images
 but make them behave like normal emojis.

Comment: Might help if you provide some images to convey your idea. IIUC, you want to make a new keyboard app. Keyboard is the input mechanism so what you are looking for is probably a new keyboard layout which is more of an OS extension... Apologies if I misunderstood.

Comment: I've edited my question, i hope its more clear now.